# Remove ALL ExtJs CSS overrides

Tags: css, extjs, internet-explorer-8, extjs4.2

Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204698/extjs4-too-graceful-need-help-ie8-component-rendering) question (and answer) suggest, I currently remove a few ExtJs "injected" css classes by including this in my Ext.application block:

```
Ext.application({
    launch : function() {
        ...
        Ext.getBody().removeCls('x-nbr');
        ...
    }

});
```

ExtJs adds the 'x-nbr' class to the body tag when Internet Explorer 8 is used (this overrides lots of CSS that ruins my page).

But what other classes does it add?  How how do I remove ALL the styles that ExtJs adds when IE renders my page?

**EDIT**

I have found a duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231105/remove-extjs-automatically-added-classes?rq=1), but the (at the time of this writing) 2 answers provided are insufficient.  I cannot change the value of scopeResetCSS in ext-all.js as that file is shared across multiple applications.  I need a fix for my application specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'br' in 'x-nbr' means 'border radius' for Ext source code. So 'nbr' would mean no support for border-radius.

another class that is added is 'x-nlg'. 'x-' is just the prefix for all the framework classes.

'lg' in 'x-nlg' means 'linear gradiend', so again 'nlg' would mean no support for linear gradient.

Ext.EventManager (for v. 4.2) declares an internal function called initExtCss. I suggest you take a look at it. Will give you an example of what is added into the body dom element based on framework environment booleans like Ext.isIE8.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing the *css*, you can **override** it with your own style.

You can include your own *css* files. By using the `id` attribute of the particular component you can override its *css* properties.