# Using Sencha ExtJS to customise an existing website or do a mashup

Tags: extjs, mashup

I'm using ExtJS 4.2.1 to add customizations to a web site over which I have no design control. You could consider this to be like adding ExtJS components to another page as a mashup.

The problem is that when ExtJS starts up it adds CSS classes, such as **x-body**, to the <body> element of the DOM and this affects everything else on the page. I need to be able to stop it doing this while still allowing it to take effect on the ExtJS containers.

I know that I can use an IFrame to contain my ExtJS customization and isolate it from the page's DOM, but I found problems with performance with IFrames, and even rendering problems in Firefox and IE so need a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

In ExtJS 4.0.2 if you set `scopeResetCSS:true` the magic happens, but in ExtJS 4.2.1 I can't found the option.

I guess you have a couple ugly options:

1. Remove the styles from ExtJS stylesheet (a long and boring work)
2. Use Ext.Element and removeClass function to manually remove the class from each element http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-removeCls

Comment: Thanks @Aguardientico. I have up-voted your answer as it set me in the right direction. I have posted my own solution along the lines of your option 2.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further research, prompted by Aguardientico's answer, I found that is is possible to do this using Sass as described [here](https://wwww.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?214736-x-body-applied-even-with-scopeResetCss-true&p=988049&viewfull=1#post988049) however I didn't want to rebuild the ExtJS CSS so I added some code to do it at runtime as follows:

```
var body = Ext.getBody();
// Remove the x-body cls from the body element
body.removeCls("x-body");
// Add x-body cls to any existing top-level ExtJs divs
body.select('>div').each(function(el) {
    if (el.hasCls("x-border-box")) {
        el.addCls("x-body");
    }
});
body.on("DOMNodeInserted", function(e, node) {
    // Add x-body cls to top-level ExtJs divs as they are created
    if (node.parentNode === body.dom) {
        if (Ext.fly(node).hasCls("x-border-box")) {
            Ext.fly(node).addCls("x-body");
        }
    }
});
```

The idea is to remove **x-body** from the **body** element and add it back to any divs created by ExtJS as immediate children of the body. Because ExtJS adds new divs as required, e.g. for pick lists, it is also necessary to watch for them being created using the **DOMNodeInserted** event.

I call this code in my application's `launch` handler, but it could alternatively be at the start of the `Ext.onReady` handler.

**Edit:**
My ExtJS application is in a container that is rendered to the body element like this:

```
Ext.create("Ext.container.Container", {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    ...
});
```

but if you render to another DIV you will also need to add the **x-body** class to your custom container explicitly like this:

```
Ext.create("Ext.container.Container", {
    renderTo: "SomeOtherDiv",
    cls: "x-body",
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The right option in ExtJS 6+ (classic) is [Ext.scopeCss](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/classic/Ext.html#property-scopeCss)

> Set this to true before onReady to prevent any styling from being added to the body element. By default a few styles such as `font-family`, and `color` are added to the body element via a "x-body" class. When this is set to `true` the "x-body" class is not added to the body element, but is added to the elements of root-level containers instead.